# Installing Cordova CLI using npm on windows xp

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-cli

I am getting the following errors while installing cordova CLI using npm tool from cmd.

```
npm install -f -g cordova

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! Error: connect EAFNOSUPPORT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at connect (net.js:766:19)
npm ERR!     at net.js:845:9
npm ERR!     at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>




npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-f" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\AmarJyotiG
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code EAFNOSUPPORT
npm ERR! errno EAFNOSUPPORT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Documents and Settings\AmarJyotiG\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am relatively very new to using cordova. Any help !

Comment: That does not seem to be *cordova* specific. Could you try removing IPv6 if you have it installed? Instructions: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_ip_v6_pro_remove.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: this is to install cordova cli. cordova has not yet installed.

Comment: i have uninstalled ipv6. Din't work

Comment: Then I ran out of ideas. For reference, look for NPM EAFNOSUPPORT error, it is unlikely related to cordova in any way.

Comment: Yes it's not. But thanks for your help.